# error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "...", user "...", database "...", SSL off with Heroku, pg 8, Vercel client

Tags: postgresql, heroku

Pg 8 and Heroku requires I use a pg config that looks like this:

```
require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = {
  driver: 'pg',
  connectionString:
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test'
      ? process.env.DB_TEST_URL
      : process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
  },
};
```

but this gives me the `no pg_hba.conf entry` error.  Setting PGSSLMODE=no-verify does not help.  This is all outlined here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-node-js

Setting PGSSLMODE=require gives me a Self-Signed Certificate error.

What are my options here?  Will downgrading PG to pre-8 even help me here?  Is this something to do with my Vercel host for the client?  Am I dumb and need to update how I'm using the config?  I'm very confused and I've tried everything I can find about this.

https://github.com/DanielJSottile/poketeams-server is my repo for reference.

Comment: Are you sure your `NODE_ENV` is set correctly? Heroku Postgres should give you a fully usable connection string via `DATABASE_URL`.

Comment: (I'm not clear why you have a conditional here at all. The whole point of environment variables is that they vary from environment to environment. Can't you just set `DATABASE_URL` in your test environment?)

Comment: Your Self-Signed Certificate error indicates the rejectUnauthorized setting is not getting passed through to the connection attempt.  Which doesn't surprise me, as I have never seen this set via module.exports before.  Is there documentation for doing it this way?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: reverted my config back to it's original configuration in which SSL was set to !!process.env.SSL (I dont think this was set in Heroku so it would just be ignored) and setting `heroku config:set PGSSLMODE=no-verify`